# html base tag blocks script

Tags: jquery, html, joomla, radix

I have a Joomla website where I've added some jquery script to an article. I added this in the content table of the mysql database. I've tested my script at localhost and this works fine. But when the page runs with joomla, it doesn't work. I searched for the problem and it seems to be the html '' tag that is the problem. Joomla generates this on top of the HTML source. I copied the html source created by Joomla and edited at my localhost server. When I uncomment the  tag, the script functions...

Can anyone tell my why the script doesn't work?

The HTML part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="nl-nl" lang="nl-nl" >
<head>
<base href="http://www.windsurfingdeinze.be/index.php/2015-02-21-17-43-42/reservatie-sup" />
< ...... >
<form>
    sups:
    <select id='id_sups'>
    <option value='0'>----------</option>
        </select>
        naam:
        <input name="naam" id="naam" type="text" placeholder ="Naam, Voornaam"/>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" id="verzend" name="select" value="selecteer uw sup:" >

    </form>

<!-- JAVASCRIPT and JQUERY -->
<!-- Script by FredGoe -->
<script type="text/javascript">    

$(document).ready(function() {
    var course_data;
    $.get('sups.xml', function(data) {
        sups_data = data;
        var that = $('#id_sups');
        $('sup', sups_data).each(function() {
            $('<option>').text($(this).attr('id')).appendTo(that);
    });
}, 'xml');

    $('#verzend').click(function(){
        var id_sup = $('#id_sups').val();
        var naam = $('#naam').val();
        var ajaxurl = 'form_afhandeling.php';
        data =  {'id_sup': id_sup,
             'naam' : naam
            };
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
            alert('Bedankt, ' + response.naam + ' de ' +response.id + ' werd voor u gereserveerd');
        location.reload();
    },'json');
});
```

});

The used sups.xml and form_afhandeling.php files are in the same directory as the index.php file. The XML file has as rights 775.

I think it has got something to do with the base href who can't find my xml and php file, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance,
Frederik

Comment: What does the JavaScript console say? What does the Net tab say?

Comment: Use absolute url instead or relative.

Comment: The javascript console tells this: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"... The error is given at the line where my jquery starts $(document).ready(function(){})... I don't understand it. When I add "<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> to my head it works fine... How is this possible?